# How to pass multiple options to bootstrap carousel's optional options object in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have been studying Bootstrap carousel from their [official site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel). Where they suggest that to pause the cycling of carousel on mouseenter event set `pause` to `"hover"`. I also want to change the cycling speed to 1sec so I tried this:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: "hover",
    interval: 1000        
 })
```

It set the cycling speed to 1 second but the carousel still doesn't stop on hovering over it. So my questions are:

1. Why doesn't the carousel stop cycling even after setting `pause` to `hover`.
2. It is said that the default value of `pause` is `hover` then why don't the carousel stop cycling on hover by default? Why would I even use `null` for `pause` if the carousel is by default not passable on hover?

**Note:** This bug only appears in firefox browser. In chrome the carousel pauses on hover.

Comment: your code should work, make sure nothing is infront of the carousel that could block the hover :)

Comment: and you should select the carousel with id like: $('#carousel')

Comment: @jogoe Nope. There's nothing obscuring the carousel. The following pauses the carousel on hovering but doesn't runs it on mouseleave `$('.carousel').hover(function(){
                $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$('#myCarousel').hover(function () { 
    $(this).carousel('pause');
}, function () { 
    $(this).carousel('cycle');
});
```

as seen here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1048

EDIT: I implemented a fully working carousel on https://www.koopensteun.be, code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="width90" src="img/1.jpg" alt="Gratis het goede doel steunen! Hoe kan dat?" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img class="width90" src="img/2.jpg" alt="Na aankoop bedanken de webshops op Koop&Steun ons voor de reclame" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img class="width90" src="img/3.jpg" alt="Wij storten deze bijdrage door naar jouw favoriete goede doel of vereniging!" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried and know that it works. But my question is: Is Bootstrap official page technically incorrect in saying that setting `pause` to `hover` should work?

Comment: Are you using the latest bootstrap release and is the problems manifesting on several browsers? I implemented a carousel very recently and in fact, it is by default pausing when I hover over it.

Comment: Interesting. On chrome it works fine but not in Firefox. And yes I am using bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: Following your answer I rechecked the site I implemented the carousel for (https://koopensteun.be/) and it seems to be working fine there in Firefox as well. I updated my answer with the full working code

Comment: I just restarted firefox and it just *king worked! Thanks for help.